What is the best way to fix the missing start script error for NPM?
I am trying to run my backend and db within a docker container but I do not think the files are properly being copied into the dist folder. Does the package.json need to be in the dist folder?
Attaching to backend-1, dynamodb-1
backend-1   | npm error Missing script: "start"
backend-1   | npm error
backend-1   | npm error Did you mean one of these?
backend-1   | npm error   npm star # Mark your favorite packages
backend-1   | npm error   npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
backend-1   | npm error
backend-1   | npm error To see a list of scripts, run:
backend-1   | npm error   npm run
backend-1   | 
backend-1   | npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-31T08_32_51_120Z-debug-0.log
dynamodb-1  | Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
dynamodb-1  | Port:     8000
dynamodb-1  | InMemory: true
dynamodb-1  | Version:  2.5.2
dynamodb-1  | DbPath:   null
dynamodb-1  | SharedDb: false
dynamodb-1  | shouldDelayTransientStatuses:     false
dynamodb-1  | CorsParams:       null
dynamodb-1  | 


version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      PORT: 3001
    depends_on:
      - dynamodb
    command: npm run start

  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5


# Stage 1: Build
FROM node:18 AS builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json tsconfig.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Runtime
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install --omit=dev

COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]


{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/server.js", 
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/server.ts",
    "clean": "rimraf dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.8.5",
    "apollo-server-lambda": "^3.13.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1691.0",
    "graphql": "^16.9.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.21.1"
  }
}



Why do you override the command back from ["node", "dist/index.js"] to start with? That follows https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#cmd
